# Acceder a ruta alojada en server desde aplicacion

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012

Como puedo acceder a una ruta del Servidor desde mi aplicacion?

```
 string miruta = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CarpetaCreada al Instalarse\Sistema";
```

Ya que si la pongo asi, se dirige al registry editor de mi computadora y yo quiero ir al registry editor del servidor donde esta instalado una aplicacion que quiero usar.

Comment: si la aplicacion corre local, va a ir a esa ruta local. no entiendo que tratas de hacer

Comment: Tendías que tener un "componente" corriendo del lado del servidor que sea capaz de resolver la clave del registro en el servidor y devolverte el valor de la clave que necesites. La lectura del registro de windows desde una aplicación en c# no es posible (O por lo menos no nativamente). Quizas puedas echar mano de esto: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regconnectregistrya

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usas la clase

[Registry.GetValue(String, String, Object) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?view=netframework-4.8)

para tomar el valor

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\CarpetaCreada al Instalarse\Sistema");   

string valor = key.GetValue("nombrekey");
```

[Read and Write Windows Registry to Store Data Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/windows-registry/)

Si se necesita leer una key de la registry remota se usa

[RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openremotebasekey?view=netframework-4.8)

con este podras indicar la ip o nombre de la pc remota

```
RegistryKey rkey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "RemoteComputer");
RegistryKey rkeySoftware = rkey.OpenSubKey("Software");
```

[How to Read Remote Registry Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566547/how-to-read-remote-registry-keys)

Comment: Pero esto solo funciona para leer el registro de la máqina donde se ejecuta la aplicación. Creo que @Manny está preguntando cómo leer el registro de una máquina remota.

Comment: si es para una pc remota solo era cuestion de ver los metodo que expone esa misma clase que recomende `OpenRemoteBaseKey()`

Comment: @LeandroTuttini me retorna null en la variable key en la maquina local, a que se debe eso?

Comment: Puede que la keyName que intentas consultar no este bien definida. Quizas debas usar `Registry.LocalMachine` en lugar de `Registry.CurrentUser`

Comment: es correcta tu respuesta, solo que termine usando vb y no c# aun no entiendo porque con vb si funciona y con C# no. Como sea me ayudo tu respuesta.